# maven test results encoding

Tags: maven

I run test by MVN clean test on my Mac, the console output looks like this:

```
 \u8F93\u5165\u6B63\u5E38\u53C2\u6570uid\u548Climit\uFF0C\u6570\u636E\u5E93\u65E0\u8BB0
```

Information:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-03-01 01:31:09+0800)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.0.3
Java version: 1.6.0_33, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.7.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

My test case is written in **Chinese**.  How do I set the test results encoding?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the following in your pom.xml:

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

May be you have to enhance that by using the following:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you encoded the characters correctly in IDE/Editor etc.?

Comment: May be you need to set the encoding of Java itself.